# Re-factoring not working in eclipse Kepler with gradle plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, refactoring, gradle, eclipse-kepler

I have setup a `gradle` java multi-project in `Eclipse Kepler`. I have the build working great. The problem is, when I try to re-factor rename a class in one of the projects, the re-factor only occurs in that one project, and does not properly cascade to the other projects. My other projects become filled with compile errors due to the previously named class references.

Is there a way to make this re-factoring work across gradle projects?

Comment: Please provide more details (how exactly did you apply and configure the `eclipse` plugin in the Gradle build, how exactly did you declare dependencies between the projects, how exactly did you import the build into Eclipse, etc.).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser - I created fresh gradle projects in eclipse and just had the plugin drive all the eclipse metadata based on my gradle build scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The solution was to enable dependency management on each of the related projects.

To do this, right-click on the project in the package explorer:

gradle -> enable dependency management

You will need to do this to all the projects which depend on the project containing the class you want to re-factor.